# I need a way to map multiple keys to the same value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Admittedly, this question seems like it might be a popular one, but I couldn't really find it (perhaps I wasn't using the right search terms). Anyway, I need something of this sort:

```
tel = {}
tel['1 12'] = 1729
tel['9 10'] = 1729
tel['1 2'] = 9
tel['2 1'] = 9
tel['1 1'] = 2
print(tel)

{['1 1'] : 2, ['1 2', '2 1'] : 9, ['1 12', '9 10'] : 1729}
```

So whenever a key's value is already in the dict, append the key to the list of keys mapping to that value; else, add the key value pair to the dict.

**EDIT**
I'm sorry if I confused the lot of you, and I'm REALLY sorry if the following confuses you even more :)

This is the original problem I wanted to solve: Given the equation a^3 + b^3, produce a dictionary mapping all positive integer pair values for a, b less than 1000 to the value of the equation when evaluated. When two pairs evaluate to the same value, I want the two pairs to share the same value in the dictionary *and* be **grouped** together somehow. (I'm already aware that I can map different keys to the same value in a dict, but I need this grouping).

So a sample of my pseudocode would be given by:

```
for a in range(1, 1000):
    for b in range(1, 1000):
        map pair (a, b) to a^3 + b^3
```

For some integer pairs (a, b) and (p, q) where a != p, and b != q, a^3 + b^3 == p^3 + q^3. I want these pairs to be grouped together in some way. So for example, [(1, 12), (9, 10)] maps to 1729. I hope this makes it more clear what I want.

**EDIT2**
As many of you have pointed out, I shall switch the key value pairs if it means a faster lookup time. That would mean though that the values in the key:value pair need to be tuples.

Comment: why aren't the values keys and the keys values, it would seem to make a lot more sense that way

Comment: @depperm That's not a given, the values might not even be hashable

Comment: Multiple keys already can map to the same value, in a dictionary.  So could you explain what's wrong with a normal dict?  Do you need lookup access to the list of keys which are pointing to a particular value?

Comment: The dictionary values are references, just make more dictionary entries to the same value.  Unless -- do the mappings somehow change and when one key's mapping changes then the other should change too?

Comment: I don't think you can have an expression like `tel['1 2', '2 1']`.

Comment: A list is not hashable, so you can't do that anyway.  You could use a tuple instead, but as @depperm says, this seems back-to-front.

Comment: do I see lists as entries in a dictionary?

Comment: @Jim I think that's what OP *wants* to happen, but can't happen this way b/c lists aren't hashable type.

Comment: I know, I'm just not sure if editing the Q is needed now. What he has entered as an "example" is plain wrong.

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer:  yes you can, but the key would have to be a tuple, like `tel={('1 2', '2 1'):9}`.  But it's weird.

Comment: @asfeynman, please tell us more about the data in concrete terms.  What is being related to what, and how must it be searched/indexed?  Maybe we can suggest a data structure that solves the problem idiomatically.

Comment: can the OP give a reason/explanation why the current values can't be keys and the keys be the values?

Comment: Just switch the keys and values.  In your scheme the values are unique.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense. If you want the values to be unique as per your example, as long as they are a hashable type (as per your example) just switch the keys/values as others have indicated. There's no data structure that will do this natively, you'll need to build your ordinary `dict` and then transform it or create a second dict that uses tupes as Keys, etc.

Comment: Values can be lists, its just keys that cannot be

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help! I will be using @mrdomoboto's solution, but will be switching the keys and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many of the comments have already pointed out, you seem to have your **key/value** structure **inverted**. I would recommend factoring out your `int` values as **keys** instead. This way you achieve efficient dictionary look ups using the int value as a key, and implement more elegant simple design in your data - using a dictionary as [intended](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Ex: `{9: ('1 2', '2 1'), 2: ('1 1',), 1729: ('9 10', '1 12')}`

That being said the snippet below will do what you require. It first maps the data as shown above, then *inverts* the key/values essentially.

```
tel = {}
tel['1 12'] = 1729
tel['9 10'] = 1729
tel['1 2'] = 9
tel['2 1'] = 9
tel['1 1'] = 2
#-----------------------------------------------------------
from collections import defaultdict

new_tel = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in tel.items():
    new_tel[value].append(key)

# new_tel -> {9: ['1 2', '2 1'], 2: ['1 1'], 1729: ['9 10', '1 12']}
print {tuple(key):value for value, key in new_tel.items()}
>>> {('1 2', '2 1'): 9, ('1 1',): 2, ('9 10', '1 12'): 1729}
```

Comment: To the OP, this is what you asked for, although it seems like a bad idea. Thus the comments asking what do you really want?

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom Uhm, not really sure what you mean by replacing my answer with your code?  I just added an explanation and better formatting.

Comment: Yes, apparently. I misread it the first time, then saw the edit go through. I apologize for my hasty rudeness.

Comment: You should probably be using `list`s as your values, rather than `tuple`s, as `tuple`s are not designed to be modified.

Comment: I chose this answer because it did what I needed at the time. However, I will be switching the role of the keys and values as suggested by others. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch, more efficient this way as you're not creating a new tuple on every addition. Updated @RoadieRich

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but I just came across this problem and here's how I solved it:

```py
class PolyMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self._map = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._map[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        for keys in self._map:
            if item == keys:
                return self._map[item]
            if item in keys:
                return self._map[keys]
        return None


pm = PolyMap()
pm[("x", "y")] = "z"

print(pm["x"])
# >> z

print(pm["y"])
# >> z

print(pm[("x", "y")])
# >> z

print(pm["z"])
# >> None
```

This doesn't keep track of key components you've used, so if you use the same key component more than once, and expect consistent functionality of **getitem**, you'll need to pass it the tuple you created it with.

The good news is, if you know that the components of your key-tuples are all unique, then you can use this without fuss.

Answer (score 2):

For those coming here via search:

First, invert the mapping

```py
>>> tmp = {1729: ['1 12','9 10'], 9: ['1 2','2 1'], 2: ['1 1']}
```

Then create the inverse mapping to get what you want

```py
>>> tel = {v: k for k,vs in tmp.items() for v in vs}
>>> print(tel)
... {'1 12': 1729, '9 10': 1729, '1 2': 9, '2 1': 9, '1 1': 2}
```